Personalizar Floating labels de Bootstrap 5
Siempre uso para mis proyectos Bootstrap 5, en esa oportunIdad estoy personalizando el formulario del bootstrap que tienen el Floating labels, pero no hay forma de perosnalizar el label que queda arriba cuando uno escribe en el campo, lo demas si pude personalizar sin problemas. Alguien ya le paso lo mismo, y pudo personaliar?
ese seria el campo:
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="" required>
<label for="floatingInput">Nombre</label>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Escriba su Nombre</div>
</div>
</div>


yo lo hice, pero lo que cambia con ese css es cuando click adentro del formulario, en el focus, yo quiero cambiar el label que queda arriba una vez ingresdo datos por el usuario, pero no he conseguido, he podido cambiar todo menos eso.

Para personalizar la etiqueta, tienes que declarar el selector en CSS de la acción que estás realizando. En este caso, cuando escribes en el input, lo que estas haciendo es un focus a ese mismo elemento.
En este caso el codigo de css quedaría algo del estilo
input.form-control#nombre:focus ~ label {
 font-size: 21px;
 color: red;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
}

Dando como resultado lo siguiente

En este caso, estas declarando los estilos del label hermano del input con la pseudo-clase focus
